# setRefreshing(true) does not show indicator

Tags: android

I am using SwipeRefreshLayout and everything is fine, when Listview has some childs. Problem is: when listView has no chileds it does not show load indicator after setRefreshing(true) call. How to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It actually does show the indicator...behind the ActionBar!

The way I fixed it was below:

```
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height = size.y;
    getSwipeRefreshLayout().setProgressViewOffset(false, -200, height / 9);
```

**EDIT**

The above is no longer the correct answer. The correct answer is below:

```
getSwipeRefreshLayout().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        getSwipeRefreshLayout().setRefreshing(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to fix it?

I faced the same issue. My fix was to provide an empty view for the `ListView`, wrapped around a `ScrollView` and a `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Something lie:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout        
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@android:id/empty"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          <View                    
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       </ScrollView>
   </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```