# SwipeRefreshLayout setRefreshing() not showing indicator initially

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have a very simple layout but when I call `setRefreshing(true)` in `onActivityCreated()` of my fragment, it does not show initially.

It only shows when I do a pull to refresh. Any ideas why it isn't showing up initially?

**Fragment xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Fragment code:

```
public static class LinkDetailsFragment extends BaseFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    @InjectView(R.id.swipe_container)
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeContainer;

    public static LinkDetailsFragment newInstance(String subreddit, String linkId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(EXTRA_SUBREDDIT, subreddit);
        args.putString(EXTRA_LINK_ID, linkId);

        LinkDetailsFragment fragment = new LinkDetailsFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    public LinkDetailsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mSwipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mSwipeContainer.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
        mSwipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_link_details, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // refresh
    }
}
```

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"

Comment: I confirm that this problem happened with me from that version on going. Earlier versions doesn't have any problems with that.
I'll post the solution if I get any.

Comment: Let me try an earlier version

Comment: Also not working on v20 for me. Which version is it working for you on?

Comment: I don't remember the version, but It was before that circle comes.

Comment: Can you use version 19?

Comment: I'm 100% sure that it's working on version 20

Comment: compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+"

Comment: you have only show swiperefreshview while on refresh, just add mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true); on onRefresh() method. this is batter way to display swipe view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setRefreshing(true) does not show indicator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484907/setrefreshingtrue-does-not-show-indicator)

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Faced with same issue. My solution -

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works well but I don't know why we need to do this instead of 
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

Comment: http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html#swipe-to-refresh-swipe-to-refresh

Comment: That's not a good solution / workaround.If the user is on airplane mode, your refreshLayout would start refreshing on its own thread after already starting the network request and receiving its response (failure in this case). On handling it to stop the refreshLayout, it wouldn't work since it didn't start yet! In other words the refreshLayout would start refreshing after you've received your response. Good luck stopping it

Comment: As I remember "posts" are sync and runs in the order of adding. So you can add another post to stop it.

Comment: It perhaps looks simplest in implementation but it is not nice. @niks.stack  solution [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28692493/1235698) is better as does not require any changes in code using it, so when eventually this bug is fixed in support lib, you just switch back to support lib SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: It doesn't work on Fragments, :( RecyclerView inside SwipeRefresh.

Comment: In addition to this, after my refresh method had completed I had to use exactly this code snippet but with `setRefreshing(false)`. If I just called `setRefreshing(false)` without the Runnable stuff, the progress indicator would never go away.

Comment: @savepopulation me to. Do you find any way?

Comment: @naiyu no i did not. but i changed it to progressbar for first loading process. and later i show swipe refresh layout. but if i'm not wrong this issue is fixed in latest library.

Comment: @savepopulation I have tried the current version 23.4.0 , but seams not fixed

Answer (score 102):

## See Volodymyr Baydalka's answer instead.

**These are the old workarounds.**

That used to work on earlier version of the `android.support.v4`, but from version 21.0.0 ongoing it doesn't work and still exists with `android.support.v4:21.0.3` released at **10-12 December, 2014** and this is the reason.

SwipeRefreshLayout indicator does not appear when the `setRefreshing(true)` is called before the `SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure()`

**Workaround:**

calling [`setProgressViewOffset()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setProgressViewOffset(boolean,%20int,%20int)) on the `SwipeRefreshLayout` that invalidtes the circle view of the layout causing `SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure()` to be called immediately.

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0,
                (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

**UPDATE Better Workaround**

Because the actionbar could got thinner when orientation changes or you have set actionbar size manually. We set the offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the progress spinner should come to reset after a successful swipe gesture to the current actionbar size.

```
TypedValue typed_value = new TypedValue();
getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize, typed_value, true);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(typed_value.resourceId));
```

**UPDATE Nov 20 2014**

If it's not very crucial to your app to show the SwipeRefreshLayout once the view is started.
You can just post it to a time in the future by using handlers or any thing you want.

as an example.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }
}, 1000);
```

or as Volodymyr Baydalka's answer mentioned.

Here is the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712) in the android issue tracker. Please upvote it to show them that we need it to be fixed.

Comment: Did you do much testing with the `delay time`?  I am using `500` on my `Galaxy S4`.  Not sure if this would be a problem on another device.

Comment: I didn't do much testing with the delay time, but I think `500` would do fine.I have tested it on the `emulator`.I just wanted to be `safe` with the `1000` milliseconds

Comment: There's no need to post delayed. you can just post. posting without a delay just means "do this thing once you're done with what you're doing now". and what it's doing now is measuring and laying out your UI.

Answer (score 49):

My solution is to override `SwipeRefreshLayout`:

```java
public class MySwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private boolean mMeasured = false;
    private boolean mPreMeasureRefreshing = false;

    public MySwipeRefreshLayout(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MySwipeRefreshLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (!mMeasured) {
            mMeasured = true;
            setRefreshing(mPreMeasureRefreshing);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setRefreshing(final boolean refreshing) {
        if (mMeasured) {
            super.setRefreshing(refreshing);
        } else {
            mPreMeasureRefreshing = refreshing;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The advantage of your solution is to keep the view offset untouched! This way we continue in conformity with design pattern specified here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html#swipe-to-refresh-swipe-to-refresh. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? It is working but I don't quite get the inner workings. Am I just missing something trivial?

Comment: setRefreshing works only after onMeasure call, so we store local refreshing flag, and on first onMeasure call apply it

Comment: I love this solution because it means the code calling the SwipeRefreshLayout can be exactly as we desire it to be, without any complications.  It basically fixed the bug in SwipeRefreshLayout.  SwipeRefreshLayout really should just be implemented this way.

Comment: This answer may looks not that straight forward, but it fixes the issue nicely through many support library versions (in my case it's 23.1.1). 

According to the ticket this issue is not fixed @ 23.2. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712

Comment: Great answer. Subclassing FTW! Needless to say, we already have to subclass to catch another annoying bug - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31452997/

Answer (score 20):

```
mRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                                mRefreshLayout
                                        .getViewTreeObserver()
                                        .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                                mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: This answer is the only one which is not a hack so it should be accepted

Comment: Just a small thing: .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener should be .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener

Comment: @mkeuch depends on which API your targeting. If your targeting under API16, you have to do API version check, and use both.

Comment: I like this one a bit more than the most upvoted answer because it's more clear why it is used.

Comment: I must correct myself, this solution does NOT always work for me. In some cases calling `setRefreshing(false)` wrapped in `onGlobalLayoutListener()` does not dismiss the loading indicator.

Answer (score 14):

With Android support library 24.2.0 the issue should have been solved!
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-bugfixes

Comment: Ssing AndroidX libararies, issue still persists

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Volodymyr Baydalka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26910973/913286), this is just a small idea that will help you to keep code clean. It deserves a post I believe: you will be able to revert the behavior easily from posting to direct method call, once the bug is fixed.

Write a utility class like:

```
public class Utils
{
    private Utils()
    {
    }

    public static void setRefreshing(final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout, final boolean isRefreshing)
    {
        // From Guava, or write your own checking code
        checkNonNullArg(swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(isRefreshing);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your code substitute `mSwipeContainer.setRefreshing(isRefreshing)` by `Utils.setRefreshing(mSwipeContainer, isRefreshing)`: now only one point in the code needs to be changed once the bug is fixed, the `Utils` class. The method can also be inlined then (and removed from `Utils`).

There will be usually no noticeable visual difference. Keep in mind though that the pending refresh could keep alive your old `Activity` instances, holding on the `SwipeRefreshLayout` in their view hierarchies. If that is a concern, tweak the method to use `WeakReference`s, but normally you don't block the UI thread anyway, and thus delay gc by a couple of milliseconds only.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can call this method before setRefreshing..

```
    swipeRefreshLayout.measure(View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,View.MEASURED_HEIGHT_STATE_SHIFT);
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

It workef for me.

Answer (score 1):

I used AppCompat Library `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3`, using your same approach and it worked. So, you update the version of that library.

Advice: `RelativeLayout` doesn't support orientation, it's an attribute for `LinearLayout`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
  ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.license_fragment, 
           container, false);ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
    // Setting up Pull to Refresh
    swipeToRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    // Indicator colors for refresh
    swipeToRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.green, 
                R.color.light_green);
}
```

Layout XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_margin_vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_margin_vertical">

    <!-- Content -->
</ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Volodymyr Baydalka use the following code as well:

```
swipeContainer.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

**Explanation**
I implemented the solution given by Volodymyr Baydalka (using fragments) but after the swipeReferesh started it never went away even on calling `swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);`
so had to implement the code given above which solved my problem.
any more ideas why this happens are most welcome.

Regards,

'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

Answer (score 1):

@niks.stack In response to his answer, I would show the progress wheel after `onLayout()` has been done. When I used it directly after `onMeasure()`, it wouldn't honor some of the offsets, but using it after `onLayout()` did.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (!mLaidOut) {
        mLaidOut = true;
        setRefreshing(mPreLayoutRefreshing);
    }
}

@Override
public void setRefreshing(boolean refreshing) {
    if (mLaidOut) {
        super.setRefreshing(refreshing);
    } else {
        mPreLayoutRefreshing = refreshing;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a good callback after onMeasure! Thnx. Was annoying the shit out of me that on the initial run the offset was off...

Answer (score 0):

My solution (without support v7) -

```
TypedValue typed_value = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, typed_value, true);
swipeLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(typed_value.resourceId));

if(!swipeLayout.isEnabled())
     swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

```
swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            getData();
        }
    });
```

previously I was using `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` inside `getData()` method,so it wasn't working.
I don't know why its not working inside method.

Although I used `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` only once in my Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

mSwipeRefreshLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

Answer (score -1):

Another workaround is to create a new control and deriver from SwipeRefreshLayout. Override the OnMeasure function and toggle the refresh again, if refresh is activated. I use this solution in a xamarin project and it works well. Here some sample C#-Code:

```
class MySwipeRefreshLayout : SwipeRefreshLayout
{
    /// <summary>
    /// used to indentify, if measure was called for the first time
    /// </summary>
    private bool m_MeasureCalled;

    public MvxSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public MvxSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (!m_MeasureCalled)
        {
            //change refreshing only one time
            m_MeasureCalled = true;

            if (Refreshing)
            {
                Refreshing = false;
                Refreshing = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```