# Hiding Android ActionBar when scrolling

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview

I want to hide ActionBar when scrolling on my RecyclerView. To do that I'm using the quick return pattern.

Here is my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/recyclerview"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/empty_layout"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adFragment"
        android:name="com.myapp.fragment.AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code to show/hide actionbar

```
@Override
public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {
    ActionBar ab = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    if (!tabletSize) {
        if (scrollState == ScrollState.UP) {
            if (ab.isShowing()) {
                ab.hide();
            }
        } else if (scrollState == ScrollState.DOWN) {
            if (!ab.isShowing()) {
                ab.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `?attr/actionBarSize` to avoid flickering.
But when ActionBar is hiding I'm still having the paddingTop.

[image]

How can I remove this paddingTop on the right screen when ActionBar is hidden ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this listener in your `ListView`:

```
AbsListView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                             int totalItemCount) {


            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            if (absListView.getId() == wallListView.getId()) {

                final int currentFirstVisibleItem = wallListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    actionBar.hide();
                } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    actionBar.show();
                }

                mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
            }
        }

    };
```

If you would have the black area at top you must:

Add this code in your `Activity`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); //ADD THIS BEFORE setContentView(...);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Now will be good, but also u need to set the space of size which is equals size of `ActionBar`. We add `Header` to your `ListView` :

```
        View padding = new View(getApplicationContext());
        padding.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        padding.setHeight(action_bar_size);
        your_list_view.addHeaderView(padding);
```

Or you can just set padding to `ListView` in `XML`, but this is bad, because the space will be cutted when `ActionBar` will be hiden.

If you want to add offset to SwipeRefreshLayout, try to use:

> public void **setProgressViewOffset** (boolean scale, int start, int end)
>
> The refresh indicator starting and resting position is always
>   positioned near the top of the refreshing content. This position is a
>   consistent location, but can be adjusted in either direction based on
>   whether or not there is a toolbar or actionbar present.
>
> Parameters scale  Set to true if there is no view at a higher z-order
>   than where the progress spinner is set to appear. start   The offset in
>   pixels from the top of this view at which the progress spinner should
>   appear. end   The offset in pixels from the top of this view at which
>   the progress spinner should come to rest after a successful swipe
>   gesture.

This must help you.

Comment: I already have implemented the show/hidde but when the ActionBar is hidding there is a blank space as you can see on right screenshot. And I want to remove this blank space when the actionbar is hidden

Comment: I had this idea too but as I'm using SwipeRefreshLayout, when I pull to refresh, the refresh animation is hidden. Is there a way to add paddingTop to this animation ?

Comment: Ouuu. I had a similar problem.

Comment: The setProgressViewOffset do the job ! Combined with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858692/swiperefreshlayout-setrefreshing-not-showing-indicator-initially I'm able to set the offset to actionbar height. thanks